# Calling Oracle Stored Procedure from Spotfire

Tags: oracle11g, tibco, spotfire

I've create a stored procedure (SP) within Oracle that has an OUT parameter of type SYS_REFCURSOR, this SP executes as expected within Oracle.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCHEMA.MyProc
(
  p_Code IN varchar2,
  p_FromDate IN Timestamp,
  p_ToDate IN timestamp,
  p_ResultSet OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) 
AS
BEGIN
   OPEN p_ResultSet FOR
   -- Obtain required data

END SF_EquipmentStatusHistory;
/
```

However when the Spotfire guy in the organisation tries to create new Procedure in Spotfire and reference my SP, Spotfire complains that it can't have an OUT parameter.

Reading this link [Spotfire Procedure Overview](http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/id/id_procedures_overview.htm), seems to suggest that Spotfire "Information Designer only support procedures that return data of the type REF CURSOR"

Can somebody please help as to how I resolve this issue?

Thanks

**Resolved:**

As suggested changing the Stored Procedure to a Function within Oracle did resolve the problem of Spotfire complaining about OUT parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SCHEMA.MyFunc 
(
  p_Equipment_code IN varchar2,
  p_FromDate IN Timestamp,
  p_ToDate in timestamp
)
return SYS_REFCURSOR
AS p_ResultSet sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN p_ResultSet FOR
    -- Obtain required data
return  p_ResultSet;
END MyFunc
/
```

Comment: The doc is inconclusive - it mentions "(also known as Table Function)". A table function in Oracle is a `FUNCTION` (not `PROCEDURE`) that returns a table of ..., see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm#CHDIIFEG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might try something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SCHEMA.MyFuctRC
(
  p_Code IN varchar2,
  p_FromDate IN Timestamp,
  p_ToDate IN timestamp
) 
Return sys_refcursor

AS
my_rc sys_refcursor ;
BEGIN
   OPEN my_rc FOR
   -- your select statement

   return my_rc;

END MyFuctRC;
/
```